# Error recuerrente IIS al ejecutar Aplicaciones VS2017 Comunity

Tags: iis, vs2017

hace un par de meses traté de configurar un proyecto de Xamarin,que no quedó por algunas librerías creo. Ahora cada que creo un nuevo proyecto y ejecuto el IIS del compilador observo que quedó inconsistente; manda una serie de mensajes de pagina script antes de correr la aplicación
[image: luego de precionar triangulo verde de ejecutar]

[image: alguna idea?]

mi configuración es la siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea del error?, será necesario reinstalar todo?